# Match until comment character not inside quotes with escape characters

Tags: regex, parsing

I want to match everything before the the comment character, `#`, using regex in javascript.

For example, if I have the line

```
opt = "include # \"everything\" # until # the # real # comment\\" # comment "not quotes (comment)"
```

I want the regex to match `opt = "include # \"everything\" # until # the # real # comment\\"`

Note that there are two escape sequences that I am watching out for as well:

- `\\`: an escaped backslash
- `\"`: an escaped quote

For clarity I have left-hand "variables", strings using double quotes (and two escape characters inside of the quotes: `\"`, `\\`), and inline comments using `#`. Also, the assignment operator, `=`. One does not need to put a line-wise comment in every line either, so `opt = "test # test"` should be matched. Just think about any config file you've ever edited......

```
opt_name = "opt value" # comment
```

---

I certainly did try on regex101, but I am not too great with regex of this complexity and am at a loss.

Comment: Please **Edit** your question and give sample data covering all the positive and negative cases.  We can't guess at what your logic is for defining a comment versus real text.

Comment: Unfortunately, your edit does not help much.  How can we tell which of these lines has a comment at the end: `test # test` and `test # test comment`?

Comment: Do you mean `^opt[^"]+".*?(?=" #|$)"` ? Try [here](https://regex101.com/r/DKIlv9/2).

Comment: I could do this. I would prefer a more general solution. I do actually have one other kind of line as well other than the option line, but I suppose this will do. sorta. What I **want** and what I have explained that I want is to match anything until a comment character not inside of quotes. If you can't provide that, then I am simply going to turn you into a pumpkin if you keep prodding me with non-answers.

Comment: Were you replying to me there?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness good idea. I quickly decided to implement matching each line more explicitly. It is actually easier to get the right parts using groups that way. So, thank you. The weird regex challenge above still stands, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use the following regex but filter out those with an empty first capturing group:

```
((?<!(?<!\\)\\)".*?(?<!(?<!\\)\\)")|#.*
```